# Secure link url for landing page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to send a user to a landing page first before they come to the real url when clicking on a link.

```
<a href="contents/landing_location.php?locationed='.$obj->id.'">
```

When the user click the link, it will go to this page.

```
<?php
session_start();
  if(!empty($_GET['locationed'])){
      $_SESSION['locationed'] = $_GET['locationed'];
      header('Location: realLocation.php');
      exit;
  }
?>
```

And then the user will be redirected to the realLocation.php

However, this link is showing up in the bottom of the browser, so the user can find the `locationed` string in the url.

My question is how to make this link is securable, so that it can not be shown to the user.

Comment: You cannot hide link, it's either on a page either not.

Comment: Edited: _My question is how to make this link is securable, so that it can not be shown to the user_

Answer (score 0):

`locationed` is using the `$_GET` method. Try using the `$_POST` method for secure redirection.